# Find a vector $v$ such that $V=\mathbb{C}[T]\cdot v.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ and let $\alpha:V\to V$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map given by
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a\\
> b
> \end{pmatrix}
> \longmapsto
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 3\\
> -3 & 8
> \end{pmatrix}
> \cdot
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a\\
> b
> \end{pmatrix}.
> \end{equation*}
>   Consider $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-vector space with scalar multiplication
>   $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i\right)\cdot v\doteq\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\alpha^i(v),$$
>   where $\alpha^i$ denoted the $i$-times composition of $\alpha$. Find a vector $v\in V$ such that $V=\mathbb{C}[x]\cdot v.$

I'm not sure where to start. I suppose the problem is asking for a generator for $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-vector space, but where I get confused is that $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ has rank $2$. How do I find a single generator? Any help/ hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The polynomial ring $\;\Bbb C[x]\;$ is *not* a division ring, much less a field. I think the intention here is to give $\;V\;$ as **module** over $\;\Bbb C[x]\;$, not a vector space, which is a term usually reserved when working over fields or at least division rings. .

Comment: I believe the right-hand side term in the definition of your scalar multiplication should $\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\alpha^i(v)$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, it should. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to take a vector $v$ such that $v$ and $\alpha(v)$ are linearly independent. Indeed, in this case they form a basis of $V$, so that for any $w\in V$ there exist unique $c_0,c_1\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $w=c_0v+c_1\alpha(v)$. Thus
$$w=c_0v+c_1\alpha(v)=(c_0+c_1x)\cdot v\in \mathbb{C}[x]\cdot v,$$which shows that $V=\mathbb{C}[x]\cdot v$.

Now finding a vector $v$ such that $v$ and $\alpha(v)$ are linearly independent is quite easy; it suffices to take a vector that is not an eigenvector, so almost any vector will do the job.